# Why d3.exit is not working as desired in d3.join

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am working with this following code and can't seem to figure out why d3.exit is not working as desired like [this](https://observablehq.com/d/fdcdec725aec2f0a#cell-196) here.

For example, the the first 3 ranks between 2000 and 2046 are as below.

```
2000, A-B-C
2046, C-E-B
```

When I select 2046 after 2000, I expect the old data (A) to move out as per the `exit` code belw. But it is not happening.

```
exit.style('fill', 'red')
        .transition().duration(1000)
        .attr('transform', (d, i) => `translate(${ 100 },${ d.Rank * 50 })`)
        .remove()
```

```js
//desired permutation length 
const length = 5;

//build array from the above length
const perm = Array.from(Array(length).keys()).map((d) => d + 1);

//generate corresponding alphabets for name
const name = perm.map((x) => String.fromCharCode(x - 1 + 65));

//permutation function - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9960908/permutations-in-javascript/24622772#24622772
function permute(permutation) {
    var length = permutation.length,
        result = [permutation.slice()],
        c = new Array(length).fill(0),
        i = 1,
        k, p;

    while (i < length) {
        if (c[i] < i) {
            k = i % 2 && c[i];
            p = permutation[i];
            permutation[i] = permutation[k];
            permutation[k] = p;
            ++c[i];
            i = 1;
            result.push(permutation.slice());
        } else {
            c[i] = 0;
            ++i;
        }
    }
    return result;
};

//generate permutations
const permut = permute(perm);

//generate year based on permutation
const year = permut.map((x, i) => i + 2000);

//generate a yearly constant based on year to generate final value as per the rank {year-name}
const constant = year.map(d => Math.round(d * Math.random()));

const src =
    year.map((y, i) => {
        return name.map((d, j) => {
            return {
                Name: d,
                Year: y,
                Rank: permut[i][j],
                Const: constant[i],
                Value: Math.round(constant[i] / permut[i][j])
            };
        });
    }).flat();

//console.log(src);

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////// 0 BUILD HTML DROPDOWN /////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
const dropDown = d3.select('body')
    .append('div', 'dropdown')
    .style('position', 'absolute')
    .style('top', '400px')
    .append('select')
    .attr('name', 'input')
    .classed('Year', true)

dropDown
    .selectAll('option')
    .data(year)
    .enter()
    .append('option')
    //.join('option')
    .text((d) => d) // text showed in the menu
    .attr("value", (d) => { d }) // corresponding value returned by the button

//get the dropdown value
const filterYr = parseFloat(d3.select('.Year').node().value);

dropDown.on('change', () => {
    const yr = parseFloat(d3.select('.Year').node().value);
    draw(yr);
})



////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////// 1 DATA WRANGLING //////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

const xAccessor = (d) => d.Year;
const yAccessor = (d) => d.Value;
//const zAccessor = (d) => d.Category;

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////// 2 CREATE SVG //////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//namespace
//define dimension
const width = 1536;
const height = 720;
const svgns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
const svg = d3.select("svg");

svg.attr("xmlns", svgns).attr("viewBox", `0 0 ${width} ${height}`);

svg
    .append("rect")
    .attr("class", "vBoxRect")
    //.style("overflow", "visible")
    .attr("width", `${width}`)
    .attr("height", `${height}`)
    .attr("stroke", "black")
    .attr("fill", "white");

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////// 3 CREATE BOUND ////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
const padding = {
    top: 70,
    bottom: 100,
    left: 120,
    right: 120
};
const multiplierH = 1; //controls the height of the visual container
const multiplierW = 1; //controls the width of the visual container

const boundHeight = height * multiplierH - padding.top - padding.bottom;
const boundWidth = width * multiplierW - padding.right - padding.left;

//create BOUND rect -- to be deleted later
svg
    .append("rect")
    .attr("class", "boundRect")
    .attr("x", `${padding.left}`)
    .attr("y", `${padding.top}`)
    .attr("width", `${boundWidth}`)
    .attr("height", `${boundHeight}`)
    .attr("fill", "white")
    .attr('stroke', 'black')

//create bound element
const bound = svg
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "bound")
    //specify transform, must be .style and not .attr, px needs to be mentioned
    .style("transform", `translate(${padding.left}px,${padding.top}px)`);

const textContainer = bound.append('g')
    .classed('textContainer', true)

function draw(filterYr) {


    const data = src.filter(a => a.Year == filterYr)

    //console.log(data.filter(a => a.Rank >= 1 && a.Rank <= 3).sort((a, b) => a.Rank - b.Rank));


    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //////////////////////// 4 CREATE SCALE ////////////////////
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

 
    textContainer
        .selectAll('text')
        .data(data.filter(a => a.Rank >= 1 && a.Rank <= 3))
        .join(
            enter => enter.append('text')
            .attr('transform', (d, i) => `translate(${ 0 },${ d.Rank * 50 })`)
            .attr('x', 30)
            .attr('dy', '1.25em')
            .style('font-family', 'sans-serif')
            .style('font-size', 'xx-large')
            .style('fill', 'blue')
            .style('opacity', '0')
            .text(d => d.Name)
            .transition().duration(1000)
            .style('opacity', 1)
            .selection(),
            update => update
            .transition().duration(1000)
            .attr('transform', (d, i) => `translate(${ 0 },${ d.Rank * 50 })`)
            .style('fill', 'black')
            .text(d => d.Name)
            .selection(),
            exit => exit
            .style('fill', 'red')
            .transition().duration(1000)
            .attr('transform', (d, i) => `translate(${ 100 },${ d.Rank * 50 })`)
            .remove()

        )



}

draw(filterYr);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>

<body>
    <svg>       
    </svg>
    <!--d3 script-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="prod5.js">
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the data bound by its value, not by its index, you have to provide a [key function](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_data):

```
.data(data.filter(a => a.Rank >= 1 && a.Rank <= 3), d => d.Name)
//this is the key function ---------------------------^
```

Here's your code with that change:

```js
//desired permutation length 
const length = 5;

//build array from the above length
const perm = Array.from(Array(length).keys()).map((d) => d + 1);

//generate corresponding alphabets for name
const name = perm.map((x) => String.fromCharCode(x - 1 + 65));

//permutation function - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9960908/permutations-in-javascript/24622772#24622772
function permute(permutation) {
  var length = permutation.length,
    result = [permutation.slice()],
    c = new Array(length).fill(0),
    i = 1,
    k, p;

  while (i < length) {
    if (c[i] < i) {
      k = i % 2 && c[i];
      p = permutation[i];
      permutation[i] = permutation[k];
      permutation[k] = p;
      ++c[i];
      i = 1;
      result.push(permutation.slice());
    } else {
      c[i] = 0;
      ++i;
    }
  }
  return result;
};

//generate permutations
const permut = permute(perm);

//generate year based on permutation
const year = permut.map((x, i) => i + 2000);

//generate a yearly constant based on year to generate final value as per the rank {year-name}
const constant = year.map(d => Math.round(d * Math.random()));

const src =
  year.map((y, i) => {
    return name.map((d, j) => {
      return {
        Name: d,
        Year: y,
        Rank: permut[i][j],
        Const: constant[i],
        Value: Math.round(constant[i] / permut[i][j])
      };
    });
  }).flat();

//console.log(src);

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////// 0 BUILD HTML DROPDOWN /////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
const dropDown = d3.select('body')
  .append('div', 'dropdown')
  .style('position', 'absolute')
  .style('top', '400px')
  .append('select')
  .attr('name', 'input')
  .classed('Year', true)

dropDown
  .selectAll('option')
  .data(year)
  .enter()
  .append('option')
  //.join('option')
  .text((d) => d) // text showed in the menu
  .attr("value", (d) => {
    d
  }) // corresponding value returned by the button

//get the dropdown value
const filterYr = parseFloat(d3.select('.Year').node().value);

dropDown.on('change', () => {
  const yr = parseFloat(d3.select('.Year').node().value);
  draw(yr);
})



////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////// 1 DATA WRANGLING //////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

const xAccessor = (d) => d.Year;
const yAccessor = (d) => d.Value;
//const zAccessor = (d) => d.Category;

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////// 2 CREATE SVG //////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//namespace
//define dimension
const width = 1536;
const height = 720;
const svgns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
const svg = d3.select("svg");

svg.attr("xmlns", svgns).attr("viewBox", `0 0 ${width} ${height}`);

svg
  .append("rect")
  .attr("class", "vBoxRect")
  //.style("overflow", "visible")
  .attr("width", `${width}`)
  .attr("height", `${height}`)
  .attr("stroke", "black")
  .attr("fill", "white");

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////// 3 CREATE BOUND ////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
const padding = {
  top: 70,
  bottom: 100,
  left: 120,
  right: 120
};
const multiplierH = 1; //controls the height of the visual container
const multiplierW = 1; //controls the width of the visual container

const boundHeight = height * multiplierH - padding.top - padding.bottom;
const boundWidth = width * multiplierW - padding.right - padding.left;

//create BOUND rect -- to be deleted later
svg
  .append("rect")
  .attr("class", "boundRect")
  .attr("x", `${padding.left}`)
  .attr("y", `${padding.top}`)
  .attr("width", `${boundWidth}`)
  .attr("height", `${boundHeight}`)
  .attr("fill", "white")
  .attr('stroke', 'black')

//create bound element
const bound = svg
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "bound")
  //specify transform, must be .style and not .attr, px needs to be mentioned
  .style("transform", `translate(${padding.left}px,${padding.top}px)`);

const textContainer = bound.append('g')
  .classed('textContainer', true)

function draw(filterYr) {


  const data = src.filter(a => a.Year == filterYr)

  //console.log(data.filter(a => a.Rank >= 1 && a.Rank <= 3).sort((a, b) => a.Rank - b.Rank));


  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  //////////////////////// 4 CREATE SCALE ////////////////////
  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


  textContainer
    .selectAll('text')
    .data(data.filter(a => a.Rank >= 1 && a.Rank <= 3), d => d.Name)
    .join(
      enter => enter.append('text')
      .attr('transform', (d, i) => `translate(${ 0 },${ d.Rank * 50 })`)
      .attr('x', 30)
      .attr('dy', '1.25em')
      .style('font-family', 'sans-serif')
      .style('font-size', 'xx-large')
      .style('fill', 'blue')
      .style('opacity', '0')
      .text(d => d.Name)
      .transition().duration(1000)
      .style('opacity', 1)
      .selection(),
      update => update
      .transition().duration(1000)
      .attr('transform', (d, i) => `translate(${ 0 },${ d.Rank * 50 })`)
      .style('fill', 'black')
      .text(d => d.Name)
      .selection(),
      exit => exit
      .style('fill', 'red')
      .transition().duration(1000)
      .attr('transform', (d, i) => `translate(${ 100 },${ d.Rank * 50 })`)
      .remove()

    )



}

draw(filterYr);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <svg>       
    </svg>
  <!--d3 script-->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="prod5.js">
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. **`If you want the data bound by its value`**, do I understand the code would have worked as desired, without `d => d` if I chose to use `i*50` instead of `d.Rank * 50` in ` .attr('transform', (d, i) => `translate(${ 0 },${ d.Rank * 50 })`)`

Comment: Sorry, I thought the data array was just primitives but now I see they are objects, I changed the key function to return `d.Name`.